# How to prevent tmux status bar from wrapping in WSL (Windows Terminal, cmd)

Tags: terminal, windows-subsystem-for-linux, tmux

[image]

I wouldn't mind so much but this is associated with all manners of spontaneous graphical glitches:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dove emoji above is made of multiple code points, triggering this bug in WSL rendering: [emojis made of multiple code points break tmux status bar rendering](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/7355)

Replace it with a different emoji consisting of a single code point. See [here](https://emojipedia.org/emoji/) for a reference.

Comment: I would keep the dove... it probably just tried suggesting you to break through all obstacles for whatever reasons... ️...